# Iphone app that opens youtube channel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

Hi Im trying to write and iphone app of the youtube channel of my church where we have upload all of the sermons so that members of the church can download the iphone app and play the sermons. Im new with x-code and everything and i was wondering if someone could help me by providing me with the xcodes for a youtube channel application, or a step by step of writing the app tutorial. Im registered as a apple dev have all of the programs to build the app i just dont know how. hope someone can help me. Thanks to all

Comment: If you have a specific question, ask it. Don't expect us to write the application for you or "provide you with the xcodes". Start off with a book.

Comment: Wow. Not only do you not know what you're doing, you don't want to learn how to do it. I don't think anyone finds that cool. People aren't going to write your app for you. Sorry if I sound harsh, but it seems like there's a need for it.

Comment: This is not the question. There are tons of tutorials and examples. Just google.

Comment: I do want to learn. I have read tutorials and videos. I've created a webview app that opens my channel and has a refresh bottom with the help of a tutorial. but i don't know how to create a back bottom and wherever i go there is no way of going back. I have search for tutorials on google but have not found so many about this particular type of app. I want to learn and if you guys know of a tutorial or a site that have info please let me know. Thanks for all of the answers guys. –

Comment: Try http://icodeblog.com

Answer (score 3):

Put this in your App Delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
   NSString *best = @"http://www.youtube.com/user/richarddawkinsdotnet";
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:best]];
}
```

Comment: yeah! like an half of app store apps! :)

Comment: I do want to learn. I have read tutorials and videos. I've created a webview app that opens my channel and has a refresh bottom with the help of a tutorial. but i don't know how to create a back bottom and wherever i go there is no way of going back. I have search for tutorials on google but have not found so many about this particular type of app. I want to learn and if you guys know of a tutorial or a site that have info please let me know. Thanks for all of the answers guys.